# Get a subset of objects from a large S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a large S3 bucket which contains thousands of files. When the files are needed, I know the keys and it is always just a few of them, maybe 50 as maximum. Files are quite small, 1KB each.

Which is the best way of getting them from a Lambda function written with Node.js?

I was thinking about something like the following fictitious code:

```
        params = {
            Bucket: "bucket-name",
            Keys: ["file_100.txt", "file_101.txt", "...", "file_150.txt"]
        };

        s3.getSubsetList(params, function(error, objectList) {
            if (error) {

            } else {

            }
        });
```

I could always loop AWS.S3.getObject() but, is there a better approach?

Comment: What is the purpose of your S3 object data? Depend on you purpose, redesign your S3 structure to get resource with better. For example: `S3://Bucket_name/random_prefix/set_ID/files`. Then you can get all files under `set_ID folder`. If that is your random `getObject`, no way is better!

Comment: The bucket is a general store for text files. Users have a view of the files they have previously read. That is the subset. Each user would have different subset of read files. And it would grow with time. I could have something like s3://bucket_name/user_id/files but that would mean I am duplicating read files for different users.

Comment: no, dont duplicate data file. You can use cache for caching frequency reading data. If it is history function, so you have to use some kind of database to store that history. Right? If so, the best way is store needed file info (`metadata: name, location, time, size,...`) in database, then just get these data from database and show it.

Comment: Just to be clear, the user goes to a page called "FilesReadPreviosly.html" which show the content of the files on the screen. When the page loads it call an API which trigger a Lambda function. This function asks DynamoDB for the list of filenames the user read before. Now I need to call my bucket to retrieve those files for this specific user. Let's say only 20 files over 5000.

Comment: You want to *"retrieve those files"* **and then do what** with them, specifically?

Comment: Read the content in memory (data.Body.toString("ascii") for each of them. And return a JSON with a property collection of that content.

Comment: I image what should be. Use DynamoDB to store file metadata, when user go to `FilesReadPreviosly.html` page, load needed data from DynamoDB. When user open selected file, call to S3 to get content. Thats all. You should show content file one by one, should not show all at one time because it will make your page slow down. => no need to get list of S3 file. If you can predict which files will be accessed frequency, you can store them in ElastiCache because the content is small but you must consider about pricing.